# the name of a software in linux which can make one console windows use many shell by switching between them

Tags: linux, shell, console

I remember there is a software in linux. When I open one console window, I can have many "console"s or shells. But they are all in one windows. By press some keys I can switch shell between them. Without opening a new console, all I need is one window.

I forget the software's name. Could you help me to remind it?

Actually I feel that using putty connect to a server can only open one console per each inputing password is a quite waste of time.
I want to have many shells by opening putty only once.
I wonder whether linux server support that or putty support.

Comment: There's [gnu screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and also [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`GNU screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [`tmux`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

Answer (score 1):

You probably talk about gnome-terminal.  Most modern terminal emulators have tabs support.  You press (usually `ctrl-shift-T`) and new tabs will be creaded.  Switching between tabs  `<something>-Fn` keys.  I don't remember what `<something>` is, because long time ago I've remapped it to plain `Fn` keys. 
GNU screen and tmux are good too, but probably are too complex for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html). It is really nice to use.